# Use mailto: in Javascript without it creating a draft message

Tags: javascript, html, html-framework-7

I'm currently making an app for mobile devices that uses HTML and Javascript. It's the Framework7 library. I have a button on my appscreen that is supposed to bring up the device's mail client.

I want the button to function just like doing mailto: but I don't want it to create a draft. I just want it to go to the mail client.

```
$$('.email-icon').on('click', function(){
    window.location.href = "mailto:";
});
```

After they click on the icon with the email-icon class, it should just bring up their default mail client. I don't want it to actual create a new message.

Comment: I think you can't do it

Comment: Ya, I think I may need to look into using a phonegap plugin.